# Genders - Nouns with "ь"

Tags: род

Is there a way to tell which are feminine or masculine if most nouns end with "ь"?

Comment: I doubt there is a way to tell if a noun is masculine of feminine at all, not only about those ending with "ь". It's like in English how to tell if a noun is countable or uncountable, you just need to remember it.

Comment: Is there a good Russian to English/English to Russian online /offline dictionary that shows the genders?

Comment: I don't know any particular one, but any dictionary, I think, must provide information about the gender. For instance in my dictionary (probably ABBY lingvo, but I don't remember) the word "тишь" is translated this way: ж. 1) (отсутствие шума) quiet, silence, 2) (безветренная погода) calm. Here the letter ж. stands for "женский" i.e. feminine.

Comment: If a word ends with _hissing sound_ letter and then _ь_, then it 99.9% probability that it is of feminine grammatical gender.

Comment: In Terrence Wade's "A comprehensive Russian Grammar" there is a whole list of rules about this. There are indeed rules and ways to tell. But long story short most are feminine, like 70% at least.

Comment: You can find the gender in wiktionary, i. e. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C - Существительное, неодушевлённое, женский род.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party but I still feel my answer would be useful. You might find the rules listed in the other two answers problematic as they have lots of exceptions and they often require some knowledge about the word: whether it's an abstract noun, whether **-арь** is a suffix or part of the stem etc. So I set out to find if there were any hard and fast rules that you could apply without looking up the word and that had no or very few exceptions. I wrote an adhoc program that queried  the well-known Zaliznyak's "Grammatical Dictionary of Russian" and here is what I found:

- Words ending in **-ость/-есть** are feminine: **ра́дость, бо́дрость, со́весть, сверхтеку́честь**. I found only two exceptions to this rule: **гость** and **тесть**.
- Words ending in **-итель/-атель** are masculine: **учи́тель, созда́тель, бомбомета́тель.** There are no exceptions to this rule that are worth remembering.
- Words ending in **-чь, -шь, -жь, -щь** are feminine: **дочь, ночь, мышь, ложь, по́мощь**. There are no exceptions to this rule as it's an orthographic rule.

These rules are worth memorising because:

- They cover 75% of all nouns ending in **-ь** (as per Zaliznyak's "Grammatical dictionary").
- They don't require you to know the meaning of a word, only its dictionary form.
- They have no or few exceptions (all exceptions listed).

Answer (score 4):

a) Any noun ending in ***-нь*** and meaning a physical entity that is not a part of a larger whole/not dependent on the other object is most likely a masculine (whence ***тень, сень*** and ***голень*** are exceptions - just like ***дребедень*** and the like, including swearing register):

***камень, огонь, конь, кремень, кистень, пельмень***

b) Any name for an actor / occupation  / instrument ending in ***-рь*** (a cognate to English *-er* in words like *maker, doer,* etc.) is masculine:

***царь, ларь, фонарь, пономарь, пахарь***

c) Any name of a month is masculine: ***январь, февраль, апрель,*** etc.

d) Any noun ending in ***-тель*** and meaning an occupation or a status of doer/maker (that is, a noun derived from a verb) is masculine (a feminine form is constructed by adding ***-ница*** to a masculine form):

***учитель, предводитель, изготовитель, родитель, свидетель***

e) Any noun ending in ***-сть*** and derived from an adjective is 99.9 % feminine:

***радость, гадость, милость, сладость, старость,*** etc.

f) This also comprises the words meaning quality and derived from an adjective, but having other than ***-сть***-ending forms:

***зелень, синь, глубь, зыбь, блажь, дурь***

Answer (score 4):

In [an excellent](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=89NUAAAAcAAJ&rdid=book-89NUAAAAcAAJ&rdot=1) XIX century book "Филологические наблюдения протоиерея Г. Павского над составом русского языка" found by @YellowSky - can not be more grateful to him for this than I am! -  following rules are listed (page 332, spelling and some words modified by me to be in concordance with modern language):

> - Если существительное, кончающееся на `ь`, есть собирательное или изображает отвлечённые качества, состояния или действия, то оно
>     принадлежит к числу женских. Таковы существительные: `чернь`, `знать`,
>     `Русь`, `учь` (this one is an obsolete word); `дрянь`, `дичь`, `высь`,
>     `даль`, `брань`, `дурь`, `блажь`, `скорбь` и т.п. Сюда относятся все
>     имена отглагольные, кончающиеся на `ь` и имена переделанные из
>     действительных и страдательных причастий, кончающихся на --`-ль`,
>     `-нь`, `-ть`, например - `честь`, `власть`, `весть`, `речь`, `помощь`,
>     `память`, `быль`, `прибыль`, `ткань`, `бить`. Все производные имена,
>     кончающиеся на `-знь`, `-снь`, `-ость`, `-есть`, `-ель`, `-овь`,
>     `-вь`, `-явь`, `-евь`, `-адь`, `-ежь`, тоже принадлежат к числу имён
>     женских,    например `болезнь`, `песнь` (obsolete, modern form песня),
>     `казнь`, `мудрость`, `гордость`, `горесть`, `свирель`,    `любовь`,
>     `морковь`, `кровь`, `вервь` (obsolete, now верёвка), `ветвь`, `хоругвь`,
>     `рухлядь`, `тетрадь`, `площадь`, `молодёжь`.
> - Если существительное, оканчивающееся `ь` означает одушевлённое существо женского пола, то оно женского рода, например, `мать`,
>     `дочь`, `свекровь`, `лань`, `нетель` (a rare word for cow that hasn't
>     gave birth so far).
> - Собственные имена областей и рек тоже рода женского, например, `Сибирь`, `Казань`, `Астрахань`, `Волынь`, `Шелонь`, `Припять` и так
>     далее.
>
> Все прочие имена, кончающиеся на `ь` и не имеющие этих трёх примет
>   остаются неопределёнными в отношении к их роду.

My personal adviсe would be not trying to memorize any rules of this kind. 
The thing is that if something is feminine or masculine in, say, 80% of cases, you still need to remember all the "exceptions" which can constitute a long list.